# Could a compiler optimisaton give an lvalue rather than rvalue?

Tags: c++

The following code:

```
int x = 0;
x+0 = 10;
```

unsurprisingly produces the compiler error

```
lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

However, is it **guaranteed** that all standards-conforming compilers will produce a similar error, or could a compiler legitimately treat line 2 as

```
x = 10;
```

which then would compile?

Comment: optimizations are not allowed to change the meaning of valid code, or the rules of the language.

Comment: The result of `x+0` must necessarily be treated as if it was a distinct object from `x` even if they would always have the same value. There is no way to interpret `x+0` as a reference to `int x`. You could make your own type where `T::operator+(int)` returns a reference to itself if you feel like it (and are evil).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is guaranteed you get an error (or more precisely, some diagnostic). Compiler optimization never makes ill-formed code well formed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, compilers must reject this.

A good description of value categories can be found here:
https://medium.com/@barryrevzin/value-categories-in-c-17-f56ae54bccbe

One of the takeaways is, the value category of an expression can be determined by looking at the type `decltype ((expr))`.

Compiler optimations do not change the types of expressions, and they generally happen after name resolution, determination of types, overload resolution etc.

Gcc is known to perform some constant folding in the front end but i would be shocked if any version of gcc compiles your example.